# How can we swap byte in a Vector256 (System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86)?

Tags: c#, .net-core, simd, intrinsics

I'm optimizing a Gaussian Filter in c#, using the new System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86 namespace (Single instruction, multiple data) found in .net core 3.0.

I'm working with Vector256 for the biggest part of the algorithm, but at the end i must do a division. I found how to go from my Vector256 to 2 Vector256 to be able to do a divison, but i'm having trouble bringing it back to a ushort version so i can output the data. I'm trying to use Avx2.PackUnsignedSaturate(vector1, vector2), which effectively give me a Vector256 but the items have been mixte (kind of a endianness, but the individual value of each of my ushort are there)

All i need would be to swap a couple byte in the middle. Using a regular loop (without SIMD) to put back the value in the output would be easy, but also a waste of time (well, i think ... hard to say if i can't benchmark the simd solution)

-I've tried a shuffle on the Vector256 casted as bytes. I'm not able to achieved what i need, it seem the byte movement are confined in their respective 128bits.
-I've tried looking at MSDN, there's no example or descriptions on those new functions, so for most of them, i have no idea what they are doing
-I've tried looking at Intel guide (https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf), While they do explain some stuff, those that i think i would need (XCHG or BSWAP maybe?), could not find them in the namespace.

```cs
var initialVector1 = System.Runtime.Intrinsics.Vector256.Create(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
var initialVector2 = System.Runtime.Intrinsics.Vector256.Create(9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16);

var convertedBackToUshort = Avx2.PackUnsignedSaturate(initialVector1, initialVector2);
```

The content of convertedBackToUshort should be :
1, 2, 3, 4, **5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,** 13, 14, 15, 16

but i'm getting :
1, 2, 3, 4, **9, 10, 11, 12, 5, 6, 7, 8,** 13, 14, 15, 16

Using `Avx2.Shuffle(convertedBackToUshort, mask)`, i'm unable to bring the 9 back on the right side (trying with several for loop to "brute-force the mask" without success)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Avx2.PackUnsignedSaturate` aka VPACKUSWB/VPACKUSDW, like many 256bit operations, works like two the 128bit versions of the operation side by side instead of like a scaled up version of the 128bit version. There is a nice image [on this page](https://www.officedaytime.com/simd512e/simdimg/si.php?f=packssdw). There are cross-lane shuffles too, for example `Avx2.Permute4x64` which you can use to put the blocks in their "natural" order if you wanted. It takes a `Vector256<UInt64>` but that doesn't matter, just reinterpret your vector before and after.

The pack operations pair well with the unpack functions (eg `Avx2.UnpackLow`), if you use those rather than the "convert" functions then you should not need additional permutes.

Using a scalar loop would indeed not be efficient, not only because it's a scalar loop but also because converting between vectors and a "bunch of scalars" has overhead.

There is a deeper problem in this question, because a Gaussian filter (or in general any convolution really) does not normally include a division, and therefore doesn't end up needing this step. Since your data is ushorts, you could use `Avx2.MultiplyHigh` to scale by a factor between 0 and 1, without having to do anything complicated.

Comment: The Avx2.Permute4x64 did a good job, my problem is now fixed ! :D  I tried the UnpackHigh and UnpackLow, but i definitively don't understand how to use it (i have 1 vector, it require 2, and passing twice the same vector aint working well for me). For the division part, it's okay, it is only a personnal project to play with simd, and it does blur the image a little so i'm happy !

Comment: @MaximeBoyer in this case, pass a zero-vector as the other vector